# How to insert multiple data into the database using a single method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, eloquent

As the title suggests, I would like to insert data into 03 tables (products, products_order, orders).
Indeed, I would like

1- I want to recover the stock_products and subtract from the order's quantity of products (`stock_actuel = stock_actuel - quantity`)

2- In the products_order table, we record the identifier the product identifier with the price of each product, the quantity and the total amount.

3-In the order table, we record the order informations such as number, dates etc.

All this in a single store or create.
here is what i did and it doesn't work.

```
public function store(Request $request, $id)
    {
        // update stockproduit
        // $stockproduit = Produits::find($id);
        $produits = collect($request->produits->stockproduit)->transform(function ($stockproduit){
            $stockproduit['stock_actuel'] = $stockproduit['stock_actuel'] - $stockproduit['quantity'];
            $stockproduit->update();
        });

        $commande = new RestauCommande;

        $commande->produit_id = 'cmde-' .$id;
        $produits = collect($request->produits)->transform(function ($produit) {
            $produit['total'] = $produit['quantity'] * $produit['prix'];
            return new CommandesProduits($produit);
        });
        $data = $request->except('produits');
        // $data->made_by = $request->get('users_id');
        // $data->tables_id = $request->get('users_id');
        $data['sub_total'] = $produits->sum('total');
        $data['grand_total'] = $data['sub_total'] - $data['remise'];
        // $data['clients_id'] =  $client->id->$request->get('clients_id');


        $data = RestauCommande::create($data);

        $commande->produits()->saveMany($produits);

        return response()
            ->json([
                'La Commande a été créée avec succès' => true,
                'id' => $commande->id,
            ]);

    }
```

My vue

```
<b-modal
      id="modalShow"
      title="Commandes"
      ref="myModalRefProduit"
      hide-footer
      size="lg"
    >
      <div>
        <div class="container mt-12">
          <div class="row col-md-14">
              <form @submit.prevent="store" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="col-md-12 mx-auto">
                <table
                    class="table table-responsive rounded table-striped table-sm"
                >
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">#</th>
                        <!-- <th scope="col"></th> -->
                        <th scope="col">Produit</th>
                        <th scope="col">Quantité</th>
                        <th scope="col">Prix</th>
                        <th scope="col">Total</th>
                        <th scope="col">Action</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="(produit, id) in cart" v-bind:key="produit.id">
                        <th scope="row">{{ id + 1 }}</th>
                        <td>
                        <input
                            class="form-control"
                            type="hidden"
                            placeholder=""
                            v-model="users_id"
                            required
                            autofocus
                        />
                        </td>
                        <td>{{ produit.nom }}</td>
                        <td>
                        <center>{{ produit.quantity }}</center>
                        </td>
                        <td>{{ produit.prix }}</td>
                        <td>{{ produit.quantity * produit.prix }}</td>
                        <td>
                        <div class="cart-icons">
                            <button v-on:click="cartPlusOne(produit)">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                            </button>
                            <button v-on:click="cartMinusOne(produit, id)">
                            <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                            </button>
                            <button
                            v-on:click="cartRemoveItem(id)"
                            title="supprimer le produit"
                            >
                            <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="font-weight-bold">
                        <td style colspan="4" align="right">Total</td>
                        <td>{{ cartTotalAmount }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 pl-0">
                        <b-button
                        v-on:click="store()"
                        variant="outline-success btn-sm btn-block"
                        >Valider</b-button
                        >
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 pr-0">
                        <b-button
                        v-on:click="$refs.myModalRefProduit.hide()"
                        variant="outline-dark btn-sm btn-block"
                        >Annuler</b-button
                        >
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
              </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <center></center>
    </b-modal>
```

the script

```
store() {
    //   alert ('test')
      const data = new FormData();

      data.append(
        "made_by",
        document.querySelector("meta[name='users_id']").getAttribute("content")
      );
      axios
        .post("/api/commander", data )
        .then((response) => {
          this.produits = response.data;
        //   this.loading = false;
        //   this.form.reset();
        //   window.location = response.data.redirect;
        })
        // .then(location.reload())
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
```

This is the error i get

`Error: Request failed with status code 405`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: check your route, may be your route is GET, change it to post

Comment: @DerickT. Error code 405 is `Method not allowed`, which implies that your `POST` route is not setup in the backend.

Comment: @tony19, @Psycho you were right, the route was get, i changed it to post, but now i get this error `Trying to get property 'stockproduit' of non-object`